# DAO test: the right way?

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, dao

I want to test my class MyTypeDAO implemented with Hibernate 4.1 using JUnit 4.9. I have the following question:

In my DAO, I have a findById method that retrieve an instance of my type by its ID. How to test this method?

What I've done:

1. I create an instance of my type.
2. Then, I need to persist this instance, but how? Can I rely on my saveMyType method? I don't think so, since I'm in the test case and this method is not tested.
3. Then, I need to call the findById method with the ID of the instance created in step 1.
4. Finally, I check that the instance created in step 1 equals the one I get in step 3.

Any idea? What are the best practices?

I have the same questions for the save method, since after running it, I need to retrieve the save instance. Here also, I don't think I can rely on my findById method since it's not already tested.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is:

Create a in memory db for testing, load contents of this db from a predefined sql script andthen test your DAO classes against this database.

Everytime you start tests, database will be created from scratch using the sql script and you will know which id should return a result and which one should not.

`See [DbUnit][1]` (from satoshi's comment)

Comment: +1... Also, DbUnit considerably simplifies this task, have a look at it.

Comment: another +1 for dbUnit.  If you do use it though, use the export to xml feature.  That way you can edit all your tables and then create the xml:  saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have much choice to achieve this. It's not a good practice to have orthognal tests (tests that test 2 things or are dependent). Nevertheless, you should really consider this exception valid and fast. You are right : persisting an object and retrieving it is a good idea to test this dao layer.

Other options include having a record that you are sure about in the database and testing the retrieval (findById) on it. And the a second test to persist an object and removing it the teardown method.

But really, it would be simpler to test loading and saving together and it makes much sense.

Comment: It seems that I'm not forced to have orthogonal tests. For example, DBUnit provides the possibility to fetch data from the database so I can assume that the DBUnit code is tested and that what I get with DBUnit is really the data present in the database. What do you think?